# What’s the number of rules needed to compute Cayley table of a group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

My note states that the Cayley table of $D_{2n}$ can be worked out from just 3 rules:
$r^n =e$,
$s^2=e$
and $sr=r^{n-1}s$.

I wonder how many rules we need to know in order to work out all the products of elements in a group in general?

I think it should be no more than knowing the product of any two generators. But could there be less?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group, especially https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group#Novikov%E2%80%93Boone_theorem

Comment: Thanks! btw I can’t understand the Novikov–Boone theorem part. What’s does it tell about my question?

Comment: It says there's no general procedure for finding an irredundant list of group elements, which is what you would need to label the rows/cols of a table to begin with.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)